# Не могу разобраться с felixge/node-mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Добрый день!
Не могу понять как вернуть результат выполнения SELECT-а из callback-функции query.
Суть в следующем: есть некий сервер на node.js который принимает POST-запросы от клиента и в соответствии с этим производит те или иные действия с базой данных mysql.
С записью и апдейтом в базу разобрался - все работает. Но не могу понять как вернуть выборку по селекту из таблицы в базе.
Для наглядности приведу часть кода:

```
// Здесь идет функция обработки POST-запроса
function accept(req, res) {
    if (req.method == "POST") {
        var requestBody = '';
        req.on('data', function(data) {
        requestBody += data;
        });
        req.on('end', function() {
            var formData = qs.parse(requestBody);
            var login = formData.login;
//Далее нужно проверить существование записи в БД 
//и если такой нет то сделать новую запись в БД, иначе обновить существующую
            selectDB(login);
           // Здесь нужно получить результат чтобы запустить условие
            if (selectDB(login)) ...  updateDB(login,score);           
            else insertDB(login,score);

                ....
});

// И есть некая функия selectDB
function selectDB(param1) {

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : '',
        user     : '',
        password : '',
        database : ''
    });
        connection.connect();
        connection.query(
            {sql: 'SELECT * from users where login = ?',
             values: [param1]
            },
            function(err, results, fields) {
                if (err) return err;
// console.log(results) - возвращает результат выполения запроса в БД, но return results - возвращает undefined
                return results;
            }
        );
        connection.end();
}
```

Как мне в function accept получить значение function selectDB?
Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос - с java script пока на вы и многих вещей не понимаю.
Полагаю connection.query вернет некий объект, но я смотрел его вывод в консоли node.js и не обнаружил в нем метода,который возвращает результат callback-функции.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужна асинхронная логика с функцией обратного вызова:

Небольшой пример:

```
 function accept(req,res){

   // ... 

   // ждем ответа <--
   selectDB(filter,function(results){
      res.render('index',{ rows: results || [] })
   });

 }

 // функция обратного вызова вторым аргументом 
 function selectDB(param1, callback){

     // ...         

     connection.query(
        {sql: 'SELECT * from users where login = ?',
         values: [param1]
        },
        function(err, results, fields) {
            if (err) return err;
            // -->
            callback(results); 
        }
    );
  }
```

Также не забываем использовать библиотеку [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) для сложных асинхронных конструкций

Comment: Спасибо большое - буду разбираться.

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, несведущему что происходит вот здесь res.render('index',{ rows: results || [] })

Comment: все догнал - еще раз спасибо! :)